# How show protoc and protobuf versions that Buf is using?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, buf

In order to help integrate Buf into our workflow, I need help figuring out what versions of protoc and protobuf that Buf is depending on.

I found in the [repo](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf/blob/e082c13dcdd8154d66ea5c83188d591cecfca7e1/make/go/dep_protoc.mk#L15) that they are defaulting to `PROTOC_VERSION := v22.0`, but that doesn't seem like a maintainable way to track versions.

Is there another way to communicate version tracking to my team?

Comment: The buf CLI does not depend on protoc and does not shell out to it. Instead, it has its own [Protobuf compiler written in Go](https://buf.build/docs/reference/internal-compiler). So you'd be tracking the buf CLI versions, unrelated to protoc.

The version of protoc you linked to is used for interoperability purposes.